# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a service that can pull data from a `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` database. This works fine on my computer, but then I run the service on my AWS server, and try to pull data from the database I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.)

My connection code is this:

```
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder;

    void ConnectToDb()
    {
        connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connStringBuilder.DataSource = @"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB";//"(LocalDB)\v11.0";
        connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "WRESTLING.MDF";
        connStringBuilder.Encrypt = true;
        connStringBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
        connStringBuilder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
        connStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        connStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        string location = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        //Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
        string temp = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\App_Data\Wrestling.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
       // string temp = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='F:\Projects\Bailey Service\Bailey Service\App_Data\Wrestling.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
        conn = new SqlConnection(temp);
        comm = conn.CreateCommand();
    }
```

My database is in the same location on both my computer and my server. I have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio installed on my server and I can connect to and view the `Wrestling.MDF` database on that server.

I have SQL Server (`SQLEXPRESS`) running on the server. but should it be SQL Server (`MSSQLLocalDB`) running? I do not see that one. Is that the problem? Or is it something else?

My service is running on the server, because I can pull data from it that is not in the database it is only the function that pull from the database that is not working on the server.

Update:

I in stalled the new version of SQL but I am still getting this same error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9laY.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w0zJ.jpg)
I have tried :

```
 //Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
        //  string temp = @"Data Source=MOXL0063\TEW_SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = True";
          string temp = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\App_Data\Wrestling.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
       // string temp = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLSERVER;AttachDbFilename='C:\App_Data\Wrestling.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
```

but nothing is working...
why?

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
```

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.nextmatch(DateTime item)
   at Service1Client.nextmatch(DateTime item)

how do I find the right instance>

Comment: sqlexpress is not localdb. Use the instance name you see in Management Studio.

Comment: Also, it really helps to READ the error message. Can not find server means no, you do not open an exception with "i have a problem in the server". Same way your car is not broken if it is stolen. And no, (LocalDB) is NOT local SQL Server express. https://www.connectionstrings.com/ has all connection string relevant info you ever need.

Comment: Crowcoder, what do you mean use the Use the instance name you see in Management Studio? use it where ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon RDS Db need first to download the driver and then connect to your database. Maybe this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.rds.html#dotnet-rds-drivers) can help you to connect with your db.

Answer (score -1):

Head over to https://www.connectionstrings.com/ and fix your connection information.(LocalDb) is not the same as a local SQL Server express. for which https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ gives.... ".\SqlExpress" as server. Which, btw., needs to have AttachDbFileName (does that still work? Not used Express for like 10 years) because it does NOT automatically attach an MDF file.

Comment: ok I guess I do not understand because it works on my labtop in debug mode. I can connect to the database and pull data, so why is the connectionstring wrong now? it is the same one

Comment: Your laptop in debug mode is using localldb, most likely. SqlExpress != localdb. Works on my machine = standard problem in IT.

Comment: TomTom- I just updated the post, can you look at it ?

Comment: Scott Chamberlain- I just updated the post, can you look at it ?

Comment: No, OUT OF PRINCIPLE. One question, one answer. Another question? Sure. ASK ANOTHER QUESTION. I answered the question you asked. Your update is totally different.

Comment: TomTom, I just did an new update and I am getting the same error from before

Comment: Scott Chamberlain can you look at the update I posted?